# Viewing results of a pipelined function in SQL*Plus or Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, pipelined-function

How can I view the results returned by a pipelined function in Oracle SQL Developer ?

I'm invoking the function using a simple `select..from dual` like

```
select piaa_extract.FN_PIAA_EXTRACT('01-JAN-00','01-JAN-12') FROM DUAL
```

and the result I get is

```
IQCFINAL.REC_PIAA(IQCFINAL.REC_PIAA,IQCFINAL.REC_PIAA,.....,IQCFINAL.REC_PIAA)
```

Allround Automations' PL/SQL developer displays the results beautifully in a tabular format, but I do not have a license for the full version of PL/SQL developer.

SQL*Plus' output isn't very good either, though better than Oracle SQL Developer's. 
Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you'd use

```
select * from table(piaa_extract.FN_PIAA_EXTRACT('01-JAN-00','01-JAN-12'))
```

Does that work?